How to fix the problem of "type 'string | Event' is not assignable to type 'ErrorEvent'" in typescript
enter image description hereexample.ts
const image = new Image() as HTMLImageElement
image.src = src
image.onload = function() {...}
image.onerror = function(evt: ErrorEvent) {...}

When i finished these code snippets above, an TS error is rasing:
Type 'string | Event' is not assignable to type 'ErrorEvent'.
i really want to know why typescript treat it as an type error, it seems correct without doubte, but why and what can i do to fix that?

i can not put an error screenshot in the question post because of my reputation is below 10, i think Stackoverflow team should optimize it, hhhh... :). Because of "a picture is worth a thousand words", do you think so?

The first param of the error is either a string or an Event. It is not ErrorEvent. This is the generic type for most errors.
const image = new Image();
image.onerror = function(evt: string | Event)  {

}

Playground
PS: Do you need the type assertion as HTMLImageElement. It works without that

why evt type can be a string on your answer. Can you give me some referrences for that?@Tushar Shahi

It is the most generic interface which typescirpt is able to relate the onError with. I am not able to find a specific onError for img. There might be a situation that TS uses the same error handler for DOM errors and other generic errors. In that case string might be a valid argument

Here's the Typescript definition of that error handler callback from lib.dom.d.ts and string apparently is a valid argument. Who knew.

Furthermore, at which situation the evt value is a string, or a string type is just for the compatibility problem resolving? I am not very farmiliar with it.
